# Proof that the covariant derivative is orthogonal to the tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Pavel Grinfeld in [here](https://youtu.be/jQTm-YyKWs0?t=1393) writes:

$$\vec S^\gamma \nabla_\alpha \vec S_\beta= \vec S^\gamma \cdot \frac{\partial \vec S_\beta}{\partial S^\alpha}=\Gamma^\omega_{\alpha \beta} \vec S_\omega\cdot \vec S^\gamma=\Gamma^\omega_{\alpha \beta} \delta^\gamma_\omega=0$$

but how he concludes that it is zero, and therefore that the covariant of the basis vectors $\vec S_\beta$ is orthogonal, is not clear to me. There may be a geometric way of seeing that the Christoffel symbols applied to  the Kronecker gamma at the end of the expression denote no change in them, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well... It wasn't an equal sign, it was a minus. Naturally, the joke is on me for falling for it, but there is something to be said about the penmanship and the [Austrian blackboard tradition](https://youtu.be/IIF8XfMda4k?t=1101). It turns out that the expression intended is

$$\vec S^\gamma \nabla_\alpha \vec S_\beta= \vec S^\gamma \cdot \frac{\partial \vec S_\beta}{\partial S^\alpha}-\Gamma^\omega_{\alpha \beta} \vec S_\omega\cdot \vec S^\gamma=\vec S^\gamma \cdot \color{blue}{\frac{\partial \vec S_\beta}{\partial S^\alpha}}-\Gamma^\omega_{\alpha \beta} \delta^\gamma_\omega=0$$

and

$$\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\vec S^\gamma\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{\partial\vec S_\alpha}{\partial S^\beta}}$$

with the blue expressions being the same due to the symmetric nature of the Christoffel symbols. In addition, the very last part of the first equation can be re-written with different notation for the dummy index as $\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}.$